# echo and cat-supresses the new line characters

Tags: shell, unix, echo, cat

Below is the example.I can see that when i use echo with cat it suppresses the new line characters.Is this the expected behaviour?I am working on solaris unix.

```
   .262> cat temp2.txt 
    20110801
    20110802
    20110803
    20110804
    20110805
    20110808
    > echo `cat temp2.txt `
    20110801 20110802 20110803 20110804 20110805 20110808
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?  If you want the contents of the file, you can just cat the file; there's no need to pass the result to echo.

If you want to preserve the whitespace, you have to quote the argument to `echo`:  `echo "\`cat temp2.txt\`"`, although that's better written as `echo "$(<temp2.txt)"`

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is the expected behaviour.

But as "Mark Reed" suggested you can keep the white space by using quotes:

```
echo "$(cat temp2.txt)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected behavior.

I don't know of any shell that doesn't do it.

It is documented in bash:

```
 $ man bash | awk '/Command Substitution/ { p = 1 } /Arithmetic Expansion/ { p = 0 } { if (p) print; }'
```

In zsh:

```
$ man zshall | awk '/COMMAND SUBSTITUTION/ {p=1} /ARITHMETIC EXPANSION/ {p=0} { if (p) print }'
```

(Edit: I removed the output of the command lines as they are pointless, as pointed out by @sehe in the comment)

Comment: +1 if you trim the doc fragments. This is not to the point. Also, why don't you state the gist (whitespace gets normalized/newlines are whitespace)?

Comment: Do you mean: `man bash | perl -ne'print if /Command Substitution/../Arithmetic Expansion/'`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think he meant `man bash | awk '/Command Substitution/,/Arithmetic Expansion/'`. There's more than one way to flip-flop. ;)

Comment: *Clarification* - The extinction of the newlines has nothing to do with command substitution (_Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting_), but is due to word splitting.

Comment: @Armali That's half-correct. *Trailing* newlines *do* get deleted as part of command substitution (but admittedly, this is not what this question is about). Those other newlines do get converted because of word splitting as the first character of `IFS` is used as delimiter, which defaults to a space, when re-assembling the tokens (this behaviour is specified by POSIX).